# Angular6-is it necessary to have all unnecessary node modules in Angular project?

Tags: dependencies, angular6, dependency-management

How can I remove all unused node modules from Angular project?

1. Is there any way to find the unused modules/packages in the application from checking in "package.json"?
2. How to test application stability after removing unused modules from application?